# The app that runs on my device is different to the preview

Tags: java, android, button, android-constraintlayout, preview

`android` `java`

`button` `positioning`

the display that runs up on my device is different to the preview. The width and height aren't fixed, and this is in ConstraintLayout. The problem is with the Button; I want it to appear lower than both TextViews. What should i change with my code? (I did try to google it, and look for an answer but couldn't find anything relevant except for the "absoluteX, absoluteY" code for the button)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/button_button_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAllCaps="true"
   android:text="order"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="quantity"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/quantity_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button_button_view"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preview looks different because you are using:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
```

which only affect the preview and have no power on the device.

Try this for putting the button below the TextView

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button_button_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quantity_text_view"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/quantity_text_view"
   .../>
```

Comment: Thank you. When are the constraintStart or constraintEnd used?

Comment: start and end are a way of saying left and right, if running on a RightToLeft layout (such as in an Arabian country) then start = right. In a LeftToRight country (such as the UK) start = left

Comment: Ah, ok, so it depends on the keyboard language? Thank you for the clarification. Why is it constraintTop__toBottomOf...and not constraintTop_toTopOf? I see this a lot, actually, with the auto-complete options; it's a bit confusing.

Comment: you can do both. its constrain_myView_toYourView. so  top to bottom says, put the top of my view underneath the bottom of your view. If you put the top of my view to the top of your view, they would overlap!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use properties to align the views

**Vertical Alignments**

`layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf,layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf`

**Horizondal Alignments:**

`layout_constraintStart_toStartOf,layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf,layout_constraintStart_toEndOf`

**updated xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_button_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="order"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/quantity_text_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```